# wifiManager.getScanResult() returns null value

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I'm searching to do a scan of available wifi networks but the method getScanResults() returns null list.

I included all permissions needed :

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

The main activity class is :

```
public class Home extends Activity {`

    Context context;
    WifiManager wifiManager = null;
    WiFiReceiver wifiReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        context = this;
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReceiver = new WiFiReceiver(wifiManager);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, intentFilter);

        wifiManager.startScan();
        List<ScanResult> results = wifiReceiver.results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
    }
}
```

The Broadcast Receiver is :

```
public class WiFiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {`

    public List<ScanResult> results;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;

    public WiFiReceiver(WifiManager wifiManager) {
        this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false);
        if (success) {
            results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            Log.e("wiFi Manager", "Done");

        } else {
            Log.e("wiFi Manager", "Scan failure");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your are assuming that `startScan()` will produce a result immediately but it actually only does what is says, starting the scan. Your are accessing then `results` variable before `onReceive` in your `WiFiReceiver` has been triggered which is why it will always be null (your logging should confirm that).

What you need to to is use a callback to get the results when they're ready like the code [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#java) does. Notice how the `onReceive` method calls `scanSuccess()` and the results are only accessed in `scanSuccess()` and not immediately after calling `startScan()`.
Also notice how they are checking if starting the scan was actually successful by checking the Boolean `startScan()` returns

Answer (score 0):

From API level 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) we need to ask Run-time permission from the user-end. Specifically ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. You need to check whether the permission is granted before wifiManager.startScan(), and if permission is not granted, you need to call requestPermissions().

here is an example:

```
public void startScanningWifi(){if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.
            permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
        
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        Log.i(TAG, "User location NOT ENABLED, waiting for permission");

    }else{
        //Start scanning for wifi
    }}
```

You will also need to include this method in the activity

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //start scanning
                    wifiManager.startScan();
                } else {
                    // Permission for location Denied
                    Toast.makeText( this,"Well cant help you then!" ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Dont forget to declare this in your activity as well

```
private final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1;
```